¿Cómo puedo hacer un programa en ensamblador para números binarios?
necesito ayuda con una cosita. Es mi primera vez aquí, pero de verdad me urge comprender este ejercicio.
Verán, estamos trabajando en ensamblador de Visual Studio, y nos pidieron la siguiente actividad:
Y ya he intentado de todo pero no encuentro una solución a esto.
¿Me podrían explicar que debo hacer o mostrarme como se hace?
Les dejo el código que intenté utilizar:
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
    msg1 db "Ingrese 5 números binarios de 3 bits:", 0ah, 0dh, '$'
    msg2 db "Número binario: ", '$'
    buffer db 4 dup(?)

.code
main PROC
    ; Imprimir mensaje de ingreso
    mov edx, offset msg1
    call WriteString

    mov ecx, 5  ; Contador de números

leer_num:
    ; Imprimir mensaje de entrada
    mov edx, offset msg2
    call WriteString

    ; Leer entrada de 3 caracteres
    mov edx, offset buffer
    mov ecx, 3
    call ReadString

    

    loop leer_num

    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

WriteString PROC
    push eax
    push edx
    mov eax, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call WriteConsole
    pop edx
    pop eax
    ret
WriteString ENDP

ReadString PROC
    push eax
    push ecx
    push edx
    mov eax, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    call ReadConsole
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop eax
    ret
ReadString ENDP

END main

Y estos son los errores que aparecen:


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Si es ensamblador, no es c#... de paso, deberiamos saber a que tipo de ensamblador te referis.. y por ultimo, aca no hacemos ejercicios.. aca ayudamos si tenes un problema en particular con ellos...

No será Visual Studio en lugar de C#? que es un lenguaje diferente (y mejor que cualquier otro lenguaje)

Cierto, gracias.

Te falta definir esas cosas???

Esta guía de aquí te puede servir: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52803496/255257 Ten en cuenta que en tu caso, en lugar de WriteFile que es lo que usa el ejemplo, necesitas llamar a WriteConsole, por ejemplo. Una vez logres llamar a WriteConsole, te quedará claro como llamar a ReadConsole. Asegúrate de establecer tu proyecto a Win32 y no a Win64.


¿Ya verificaste que esté la compilación para x86?

